# how to check the checked checkbox in ModelMultipleChoiceField in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
{% for choice in form.options.field.choices %}
    <div class="te">
        <label class="te">{{ choice.1 }}</label>
        <label class="te"><input type="radio" data-type="{{ text }}" name="val_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.0 }}" class="options" /></label>
        <label class="te"><input type="radio" data-type="{{ text }}" name="val_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="0" class="options"/></label>
    </div>
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{ choice.0 }}" id="val_{{ forloop.counter }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

The above code displays the label and radio buttons but how can I check which checkbox is checked in the loop

When i use this `{{ form.options }}` it is showing correctly checked checkboxes and unchecked checkboxes.

I tried **choice.isChecked** in loop but it is true always. How can I solve this problem.

If I print choice in loop it show

```
(1L, u'test 1')
(2L, u'test 2')
(3L, u'test 3')
```

Comment: Just a thought, can you not use javaScript to achieve this?

Comment: @Anzel there is a way to do this with django template itself..

Comment: then `{%ifequal form... choice...%}selected="selected"{% endif %}` may just be what you want

Comment: i.e. compare `form.options.value` to each `choice.0` ...I won't ask why you want both a hidden checkbox and a pair of radio buttons for the same field... :)

Comment: what's the output of `{{form.options}}`?

Comment: @Anentropic `form.options.value` return `[2L, 3L]` how to convert and compare

Comment: @Anzel output of form.options will be list of label and checkbox

Comment: @Relicset, then try compare `{%if equal form.options.value choice.0 %}...{% endif %}`

Comment: @Anzel form.options.value rerutns [1L, 2L] but choice.0 is 1 or 2 or 3. Can you understand

Comment: use stringformat and check `if..in` then?? I don't get what you don't get

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator

Comment: you should really learn the templates basic as @Anentropic points. It will save you tons of time in future if you have thorough understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better explanation will be a code example, compare the values using `if/in`:

#### Edited

Thanks for @Anentropic pointing out, I didn't pay enough attention, here is the edited one without using `stringformat`:

```
{% if choice.0 in form.options.value %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want that stringformat stuff... @relicset said `form.options.value` returned `[1L, 2L]` i.e. list of integers so converting `choice.0` to a string isn't going to work

Comment: @Anentropic, thanks for pointing out this. I really wasn't paying attention to what the element in list, after giving all the hints to OP. answer edited

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_checked` for **checkbox**, it works for me.

Comment: do you mean `choice.is_checked` in the above example? It doesnt work for me :(